# Cannot run Rscript from Linux command line but be able to run it from RStudio Workbench

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

I'm trying to run a simple R print function from Linux terminal but it failed due to loadNamespace error. I also cannot install that package from here because Rscript returns the same error.

Rscript failed due to missing keyring package:

[image]

However, I'm able to run it from Rstudio Workbench built-in terminal (same server)

It worked fine in Workbench:

[image]

Do you know what I'm missing here?

I'm expecting Rscript should work as same as what I'm running from Rstudio Workbench terminal

Edit: I checked .libPaths() and seeing that the default path is pointing to version R 4.3 from Linux terminal but 4.2 in Workbench. Not sure how to sync these versions to 4.2 only.

Comment: Please enhace you question describing your system installation in more detail.

Comment: Does `R.home("bin")` return the same value in both situations? It sounds like the Workbench is setup to user a different R version than the system default.